# Generalisation of affine transformation: transformations that map minimal surfaces to minimal surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We know that affine transformations map geodesics to geodesics.

Is there any known set of transformations that map minimal surfaces to minimal surfaces?

I am looking for setups for Riemann Manifolds.